# No love for android specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've retagged an Android json question to Android-json a few times now, but just a moment ago I discovered that the [Android-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-json) tag only has 77 (!!!) questions in it, compared to 7272 for the combination of [android and json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+json) ... even though Android's wiki asks specifically to use the Android-specific tags.

This basically means that I'm probably doing the question more harm than good attention-wise, because that tag clearly isn't getting any.

Have people just given up retagging in the android tag because of the constant flood of low-level, duplicate questions that could be answered by http://lmgtfy.com/ and copying the title or am I missing something here?

Comment: How is JSON even specific to Android? JSON is JSON regardless of how you are creating or consuming it.

Comment: Why does there need to be an [android-json] tag? Is there any more specific (and valid) reason than "they are questions about both Android and JSON"?

Comment: Don't ask me, I'm just following the Android-tag wiki ... I just presumed that that was reason enough, and that the Android questions containing the json tag often had more to do with httpPost or something, so they wanted to create a separate area for Android as to not bug the hell out of regular java programmers following the json tag or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original recommendation to "use Android-specific tags" was added by Robert Harvey in 2011. The example he mentions is the tag [android-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent) which should be preferred over the tag [intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intent).

The recommendation to use the [android-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-json) tag has only been [added recently](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3625001/revisions), but with no further information as to why such a tag would be needed. There seem to be no good arguments for the [android-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-json) tag, so I have removed that recommendation from the tag wiki.

The "use Android-specific tags" recommendation still may need further improvements because [intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intent) is a synonym of [android-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent) nowadays. So if the recommendation is still valid, there should probably be a better example.

Comment: It doesn't seem like `android-intent` even needs to exist unless `intent` needs to be disambiguated.